# How to get a text node without spaces at the edges?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument

How do I get the first text node back from my parent without spaces at the edges?

Node:

```
<p>Hello <b>World</b> by.</p>
```

You must get the first word without spaces at the edges:

→Hello←

Such Xpath query:

```
p/[normalize-space(text()[1])]
```

Return an error:

DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMXpath:query()` does not allow Xpath expressions with scalar results. You will have to use `DOMXpath::evaluate()`.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<p>Hello <b>World</b> by.</p>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(p/text()[1])', $document)
);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "Hello"
```

The string function has to be on the outside. So that you first select the nodes, then cast the result to string. `p` selects `p` children of the context node. `//p` selects any `p` element node in the document. So `p/text()[1]` are all first (position) text child nodes inside `p` children.

`normalize-space()` will cast the first node (from the fetched list) into a string, strip trailing/leading whitespaces and replace all groups of whitespace inside with single spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this XPath:

```
/p/text()[1]
```

and possibly this one if your XPath engine supports this sort of expressions:

```
normalize-space(/p/text()[1])
```

Comment: Question: so `/p/text()[1]` selects `Hello` and `/p/text()[2]` selects `by.`; what selects `World`?

Comment: @JackFleeting, `World` is child text node of `b`, i.e.: `/p/b/text()`

Comment: Phew! I feel much better, now that all 3 are under control :); thanks!

Comment: @JackFleeting, no problem :)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk, Sorry, Kirill, not working this query... Message: Non-standard output. See for yourself - [link](http://xpather.com/U1id11Af). I tried so: `[normalize-space(/p/text()[1])]` not working... so ... : `parent::node()[normalize-space(/p/text()[1])]` so ... : `//node()[normalize-space(/p/text()[1])]` - not working, not working, not working...

Comment: @АндрейБочкин, in this case you firstly have to extract the value by using this query: `/p/text()[1]` and then in your XPath engine (framework which actually runs the XPath query) trim the string

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the first text node back from my parent without spaces at the edges?

You can't. XPath can either select nodes from the source document exactly as they are, or it can construct values such as strings, numbers, or booleans. (Or in XPath 2.0, a much wider range of data types.).

So you can either select the text node, as is (that is, with spaces included) using

```
/p/text()[1]
```

or you can return a string constructed by trimming the text node:

```
normalize-space(/p/text()[1])
```

But with some XPath APIs, you can only use the first kind of expression (one that returns nodes), or if you want to use the second kind (one that returns strings), you have to invoke it differently.

Note that both these expressions are very fragile: they're going to produce useless results if the source document differs very slightly from your sample input.